# Relation two database and make join yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Can you help me. How to relate it and make a join
. i get [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miNmv.png) has no relation named "project".
i using ActiveRecord with my code :

```
$posts = MaKantor::find()
    ->leftJoin('project.track', '`track`.`id_office` = `m_kantor`.`kantor_id`')
    ->with('project.track')->where(['collecting_id' => $model->collecting_id])
    ->all();
```

and config

```
    'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
    'db2' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_master',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
```

Comment: whats with using `joinWith` along with `leftJoin` for the same table `project.track`?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `with('relationName')` in query, relation function needs to be defined in `MaKantor` model.
For example :

```
public function getProject()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Project::className(), ['id' => 'project_id']);
}
```